# Bound tableview not being filled at startup

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I started learning about cocoa binding today and have successfully got it to work with one exception. That is, when I fill the bound array at startup, the tableview does not reflect this data until I add a new entry from the UI, at which point it will show the rest of the data that was in the array.

Do I need to add some code to 'refresh' the tableview after filling the array it is bound to?

Edit: here is my load method called from `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)load
{
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *savedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"components"];
    if (savedArray != nil)
    {
        NSArray *oldArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedArray];
        if (oldArray != nil) {
            _components = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray];
        } else {
            _components = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
}
```

Where `_components` is the bound source for the `NSTableView`

Comment: I work in iOS, not on Mac OSX, but I guess it's the same way of thinking. It depends when you fill your array. If your UITableView already loaded, at the end of your filling array, you need to do `[yourTableView reloadData];`

Comment: Are you using an NSArrayController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to have the table populated at launch would be to call `load` from within your `init` method rather than waiting until `awakeFromNib`. For example:

```
- (id)init {
     if ((self = [super init])) {
         NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         NSData *savedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"components"];
         if (savedArray != nil)
         {
             NSArray *oldArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedArray];
             if (oldArray != nil) {
                _components = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray];
             } else {
                _components = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             }
         }
     }
     return self;
}
```

(Note you should change this to the designated `init` method for the class you're using).

What is happening now is that before `awakeFromNib` is called, the `NSArrayController` is being created, and its initial content is being set to a `nil` array (since `_components` hasn't been created yet). Then `awakeFromNib` is called, and you are creating `_components` array, but in a way that is not key-value-observer-compliant (you are setting the instance variable directly, which doesn't allow the `NSArrayController` to know that you've modified the array it's interested in).

By creating the `_components` instance variable earlier on in `init`, you assure that it will be available by the time the `NSArrayController` is unarchived from the nib file. It can then set its initial contents to that array so there is data in the table view when the window appears.

Regarding your comment about how to modify `_components` in a way that is KVC/KVO compliant, there are a couple of different ways, some of which are more efficient than others. You could call `mutableArrayValueForKey:` like so:

```
 [[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"components"] addObject:theObject];
```

See [Troubleshooting Cocoa Bindings: My collection controller isn't displaying the current data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002148-182809).

A more efficient way, though, is to add and remove items from the `NSArrayController` itself rather than adding and removing from the underlying array. This lets the array controller know that changes are being made as well as letting the array controller handle modifying the underlying array's contents. See [Programmatically Modifying a Controller’s Contents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/CntrlContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002147-183285-BBCDFJHD).

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! I would be interested to know too how I could modify `_component` at a later stage in a KVO compliant way if it was necessary to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the common step to follow for the table view are:

- Put the tableview in your view controller ( through xib or programmatically )
  and reference outlet to your view controller (eg: call it myTableView )
- bind the delegate and datasource to your view controller ( through xib or programmatically)
  (delegates in your view controller are `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate`)
- keep an array (maybe as properties of your view controller, let's suppose to call it `NSMutableArray * mySource`) and fill up with some objects
  (eg: this could be done in your `viewDidLoad` if not yet populated)
- implement the delegated methods of tableview like:

  - `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` that define the number of sections in your tableview (for now you could simply return 1 )
  - `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` that should return your datasource array count (`return [self.mySource count]`)
  - `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` that dequeue/create the cells to present into your myTableView
- Once the UI views have been loaded call the method of your table view `[self.myTableView reloadData]` (NB: i suggest you to call it at least in the `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` to be sure it will be really performed, or after pressing button in your view).

Then, each time you will add an item and you want to show the updated datsource in the tableview, simply call `[self.myTableView reloadData]` again.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not sure why this is upvoted... Question is about `NSTableView` and bindings, not `UITableView` and iOS...

Comment: @NSGod In osx you could have a similar approach, using  `numberOfRowsInTableView` and `objectValueForTableColumn` instead. Anyway i think it could be useful for someone, even though you could find a lot of question about tableview population (by reading the title an keeping the objective-c tag this question could be searched also for iOS cases i think)

Comment: The point is, the OP is using bindings with an `NSArrayController` to provide the content of the table view, not the table view data source protocol methods (`numberOfRowsInTableView:` and `objectValueForTableColumn:`). Bindings aren't yet available for iOS AFAIK. When using an `NSArrayController` and bindings, there's no need to call `reloadData`, or implement the datasource methods; the contents of the table view are updated automatically when the underlying array is modified in a KVC/KVO-compliant manner.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly do you fill the bound array at startup? Do you use NSArray or NSMutableArray? I don't know what you problem is, but the possible reasons for bindings not being updated:

- setting instance variable directly, not via property;
- modifying NSMutableArray state. For example, `[self.mutableArrayProperty addObject:@"Value"]` won't update bindings bound to mutableArrayProperty.

Bindings rely on Key-Value Observing and they are updated when some value is set to bound property, not when returned by bound property object changes its state.

Comment: I added the code I use to fill the array to my question. I think I need to look into your 2nd suggestion!

Comment: I've had a look into that but I can't figure it out... I've tried the NSTableViewDataSource protocol way too but I couldn't get that to work alongside cocoa bindings. Any ideas based on the code I added?

Comment: @doovers Have nothing to add, NSGod has explained everything in his answer.